# ¿Cuál es el error en esta funcion? Me da error

Tags: sql, sql-server, funciones

```
Create function Alumnosss
(
@codigo int
)
returns table
as
return (select (e.Nombre + e.Apellido) as Nombre, e.CentroEducativo as Colegio,
(n.NotaEspañol+n.NotaSociales+n.NotaNaturales+n.NotaMatematicas)/4 as Promedio
from Estudiantess e inner join Asignatura a
 on e.IdEstudiante = a.IdEstudiante  inner join Notas n on e.IdEstudiante = n.IdEstudiante
where e.IdEstudiante = @codigo
```

Me da el error de "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Alumnosss, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '@codigo'." dandome a entender que lo que dice "Create function Alumnoss" está mal.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: creo que falta cerrar el paréntesis del `return`

Comment: O podrías quitar el paréntesis que no sirve de nada.

Answer (score 3):

Te faltó un paréntesis para cerrar el subquery del return, algo así:

```
Create function Alumnosss
(
@codigo int
)
returns table
as
return (select (e.Nombre + e.Apellido) as Nombre, e.CentroEducativo as Colegio,
(n.NotaEspañol+n.NotaSociales+n.NotaNaturales+n.NotaMatematicas)/4 as Promedio
from Estudiantess e inner join Asignatura a
 on e.IdEstudiante = a.IdEstudiante  inner join Notas n on e.IdEstudiante = n.IdEstudiante
where e.IdEstudiante = @codigo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso un plugin en VS Code llamado Rainbow Brackets que te indica donde abren y cierran los paréntesis, llaves y corchetes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me alegro mucho de que uses dicho *plugin*. ¿ Cual es la respuesta a la pregunta ?

Comment: como lo indica la imagen, te falta un parestesias al final

Comment: ¿ Y la razón por la que has preferido colocar una imagen (que no todo el mundo puede ver) y contar las virtudes del *plugin* de marras, en lugar de **responder adecuadamente a la pregunta**, es ??

Comment: que no se puede colorear el texto en lo que se escribe en stack overflow?

Comment: @Gustavo Cantero pudo contestar la pregunta sin necesidad de colorines. No era tan difícil escribir "Te faltó un paréntesis al final" y LUEGO complementarlo con tu imagen ¿o si?